# A quick cutesy riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I'm thinking of a word.

> It's money earned that you can't use 
>   Do this in a fight, you'll have a bruise 
>   Say it long or keep your shoes 
>   The death of poor old Moose...

Comment: I intended Moose to be a name. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Oh.  I figured we were dealing with Møøse and sisters.

Comment: That being said, it works either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is

> Lose

---

Explanation

> The parts of the riddle use the word *lose* 4 ways (some of which are arguably lateral.)

It's money earned that you can't use

> *lost* 
>  Money that is lost can't be spent

Do this in a fight, you'll have a bruise

> *lose* 
>  If you lose a fight you may end up bruised

Say it long or keep your shoes

> *loose* 
>  Say lose "long" to add the extra o. If your shoes are loose you might lose them (otherwise, you keep them.)

The death of poor old Moose...

> *loss* 
>  Loss is the condition of losing. The death of Moose is a loss. I am saddened that Moose from Frasier died.

(Eutherpy, cr0 both had good answers but I wanted to give a complete answer for lurkers.)

Comment: The "a word" part of the question had me stuck between lose, lost, loose...loss was too much of a stretch in the mindset I approached this with. I imagine Eutherpy was feeling the same. Now I see

Comment: I think Eutherpy got this one, as he answered with 2 of the 3 variations on "a word" - lose and loose. I guessed lost, and you revealed loss as the explanation for the Mu-character Moose

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot and kind of vague, but is it...

> LOOSE / LOSE?

Money earned that you can't use:

> "loose money"

If you

> lose a fight

you'll have a bruise.

I think the "Say it long or keep your shoes" has something to do with

> your shoelaces being loosely tied

and the last verse I pretty much based on rhyme :)

Comment: Your answer is what I intended but could you address the lines individually? Edit: Took away correct answer until I'm a bit happier with the explanation line for line.

Comment: @BenjaminBraun I tried to be a bit more precise and edited my answer.

Comment: Why can't you use loose money?

Comment: @Eutherpy still don't have an explanation for the last line, also for the first line I agree with paste.

Comment: I think Moose is referring to a famous character, can't quite put my finger on who...

Answer (score 4):

> Lost

---

It's money earned that you can't use

> "They paid me cash for mowing the lawn, but now the money is ____!"

Do this in a fight, you'll have a bruise

> "Where'd you get that black eye?" "Oh, I ____ in a fight..."

Say it long or keep your shoes

> Say it long ***or*** keep your shoes. I want to keep my shoes, so I ***don't*** say this word long... Does "lost" make sense here? Still not sure about this one. Looooooooooooooooooost. Laaaaaaaaaaaaawst.

The death of poor old Moose...

> [Moose, the dog star in the hit show Frasier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moose_%28dog%29), died in ***Los***(t) Angeles

Comment: Still not quite it. Maybe it will make more sense if you  consider this riddle in the modern day.

Comment: Also doesn't require outside knowledge.

Comment: @BenjaminBraun it seems like it does, though, given the last line (Moose is capitalized, like a name, indicating that their death is something we should have some knowledge of)

Comment: I just pulled the name Moose out of my head, call it a poorly executed red herring then. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Charge

It's money earned that you can't use

> like a credit charge

Do this in a fight, you'll have a bruise

> rushing forward toward a person

Say it long or keep your shoes

> saying it "long": chaaaaaaaaarrge!! involves runnning

The death of poor old Moose...

> A moose charging at something bigger can kill it

Comment: Also interesting. But the keep your shoes and the Moose bit are stretches.

Comment: You're interpretation of "say it long" is what I was going for, but with a different word :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit of a stretch, but the word might be

> Super

It's money earned that you can't use

> Super, as in superannuation. Funds kept for retirement

Do this in a fight and you'll have a bruise

> Not too sure on this one, maybe a super in wrestling, where you jump off the ropes onto the opponent? You may end up with a bruise from the landing

Say it long or keep your shoes

> Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, it's a pretty long word

The death of poor old Moose

> Again, not too sure. Possibly the death of superman?

Answer (score 0):

is it

> a Bank?

It's money earned that you can't use

> Because you have it in your savings account

Do this in a fight, you'll have a bruise

> If you hit someone with a chair (WWE)

Say it long or keep your shoes

> If you are going to stay in the bench in your next (baseball) game?

The death of poor old Moose.

> Old Moose, or any company that "died" to bankruptcy.

Comment: Interesting but the baseball bit seems to be a stretch. Bank was not what I intended.

Comment: dang it. I knew the baseball part was too much XD.